# What is the difference between asp.net , vb.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Actually I am creating a website and i am using ASP.NET using c# , i would like to know that when we use ASP.NET and when we use C# and Basically What are their roles?(same for VB.NET)

Comment: ASP.NET is not a programming language; it's a web framework that requires a language to use it. Both C# and VB are .NET languages that can use the ASP.NET framework.

Comment: If ASP.NET is a web framework then what is .NET framework?

Comment: ASP.NET is a framework built on top of the .NET Framework containing helper classes for making web sites/web services/web servers (etc.). The .NET Framework alone is just a general framework containing helper classes for any kind of application.

Comment: It is technically possible to create C#/VB.NET applications without using the .NET Framework, but your app will not be able to do anything other than basic logic, loops and math unless you write your own CLR framework in the process (through C/C++).

Comment: got it ..Thank for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is a framework specified for websites, It is used in the backed of the server the same way PHP is. It is used to do commands in the server which might include database operations.

C# and VB.net are programming languages both supported by ASP.NET, They are part of the .NET framework which is a more general framework which includes both desktop application tools as well as web-tools such as ASP.net

Comment: You are welcome, If you have any further questions don't hesitate to let me know. And if this answered your question dont forget to mark it as an answer!

Comment: yeah sure :) ..